# Is there a software to monitor all the ports opened and which programs are using each of them?

Tags: security, ports, packets

Also, that we can specifically know which running program is using certain ports and what kind of information they are sending and where specifically?
This will work for many people to prevent MIM attacks, trojans, keylogger connections, etc.
I know I can partly do this by netstat command on cmd. But what I need to know is that if there is a software that does all of this in once? (Excluding common AVs like Norton, McAfee, Webroot, etc.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to the simple  `netstat -an` invocations, you'll find additionnal usefull informations on what port is opened, what files are used, with:

- unix (linux, macOSX, solaris, many) :  [lsof (nice presentation by daniel miessler)](http://danielmiessler.com/study/lsof/)

  then for the content of the packets : [tcpdump (same presenter, nice intro)](http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/)
- windows : sysinternal's  [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)

  then for the content of the packets (+ statistics, decoding, etc): [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Thats a very useful information there!

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you nmap, it has a lot of features. http://nmap.org/