# How to check which process in bound to a particular port?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, netstat

I am getting some error in an application like:

```
Failed to bind to socket 192.168.122.1:87 : Address already in use
```

so I want to see which process is using this socket.

Is there any way to do this via `netstat`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105418/what-port-is-a-given-program-using

Comment: or [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14225355/1841533) (showing also the alternative for linux/unix/mac in addition to the windows ones)