# How to unlisten the socket without having root privilege?

Tags: python, shell, sockets, ubuntu

I have met the error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Then I go to that port to find if something in there by:

```
netstat -ant | grep :5000
# result is
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

being listened, I do not know what process it is. Is there any way to clean this socket?

Comment: As root you can use the `-p` flag to `netstat`/`ss` to find out the listening process.

Comment: I do not have root privilege @Etan Reisner

Comment: Duplicate: [How to check which process in bound to a particular port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229028/check-which-process-in-bound-to-a-particular-port).

Comment: @Hellolad If you don't have root privilege, how you want to kill that process then when you know which one it is?

Comment: Try: `lsof -i` (it's not by default, so you've to install it if you can).

Comment: `fuser -v 5000/tcp` should give you the pid

Comment: possible duplicate of [What port is a given program using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105418/what-port-is-a-given-program-using)

Comment: See also: [How to check opened/closed port on my computer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/538208/how-to-check-opened-closed-port-on-my-computer), [Unable to bind to port 80 [bitnami, OSQA, Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/269718/unable-to-bind-to-port-80-bitnami-osqa-ubuntu-12-04).